# Animations and mediaquery in React without css

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to use animations and media query in react without css only using javascript or jsx?

Answer (score -1):

Sure but you have to properly configure your bundler or else everything has to be inline css.

Comment: Is there a library to add via npm?